# OData $expand Contains Incorrect Context Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

Using an ASP.NET Web API 2 OData service I have exposed the the following endpoint:

```
/entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3('key')/entity4('key')
```

When I execute `/entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3?$expand=entity4` I receive a JSON response with the **correct** `"@odata.context"`:

```
"@odata.context": "https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('ket')/entity3",
 "value": [
{
  ...,
  "entity4@odata.context": "https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3('key')/entity4",
  "entity4": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
},
...
```

When I execute `/entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3('key')?$expand=entity4` however, I receive an **incorrect** `"@odata.context"` with two keys:

```
"@odata.context": "https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('ket')/entity3",
 "value": [
{
  ...,
  "entity4@odata.context": "https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3('key')('key')/entity4",
  "entity4": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

This causes an exception when executing with Microsoft's OData Client:

`"The context URL 'https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3('key')('key')/entity4' is invalid."`

Well no kidding. What could be causing this?

**Update**

I've logged an issue [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/883). We'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround:

Using a `$filter` instead of a key: `/entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3?$filter=Key eq 'key'&$expand=entity4` provides the correct response:

```
"@odata.context": "https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('ket')/entity3",
"value": [
{
  ...,
  "entity4@odata.context": "https://host:port/$metadata#entity1('key')/entity2('key')/entity3('key')/entity4"    ,
  "entity4": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```